# Ubuntu Boot Really Slow

Tags: boot, grub2, suspend

I have an SSD and the boot was really fast. It's a new PC a few weeks old. Now the boot into ubuntu 20.04 is really slow, and after resume it's really slow to allow me to enter my login pwd. What might be causing this?

I've had nothing but bugs and headaches putting this 20.04 on my new PC.

```
    System-Product-Name:~$ journalctl -b
-- Logs begin at Wed 2020-12-16 01:50:13 IST, end at Sat 2021-01-02 14:00:33 IS>
Jan 02 13:39:38 bryan-System-Product-Name kernel: Linux version 5.4.0-58-generi>
Jan 02 13:39:38 bryan-System-Product-Name kernel: Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boo>
Jan 02 13:39:38 bryan-System-Product-Name kernel: KERNEL supported cpus:
Jan 02 13:39:38 bryan-System-Product-Name kernel:   Intel GenuineIntel
Jan 02 13:39:38 bryan-System-Product-Name kernel:   AMD AuthenticAMD
Jan 02 13:39:38 bryan-System-Product-Name kernel:   Hygon HygonGenuine
Jan 02 13:39:38 bryan-System-Product-Name kernel:   Centaur CentaurHauls
Jan 02 13:39:38 bryan-System-Product-Name kernel:   zhaoxin   Shanghai  
Jan 02 13:39:38 bryan-System-Product-Name kernel: x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE fea>
Jan 02 13:39:38 bryan-System-Product-Name kernel: x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE fea>
Jan 02 13:39:38 bryan-System-Product-Name kernel: x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE fea>
Jan 02 13:39:38 bryan-System-Product-Name kernel: x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE fea>
Jan 02 13:39:38 bryan-System-Product-Name kernel: x86/fpu: xstate_offset[2]:  5>
Jan 02 13:39:38 bryan-System-Product-Name kernel: x86/fpu: xstate_offset[9]:  8>
Jan 02 13:39:38 bryan-System-Product-Name kernel: x86/fpu: Enabled xstate featu>
Jan 02 13:39:38 bryan-System-Product-Name kernel: BIOS-provided physical RAM ma>
Jan 02 13:39:38 bryan-System-Product-Name kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000000>
Jan 02 13:39:38 bryan-System-Product-Name kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000000>
Jan 02 13:39:38 bryan-System-Product-Name kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000000>
Jan 02 13:39:38 bryan-System-Product-Name kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000000>
Jan 02 13:39:38 bryan-System-Product-Name kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000000>
Jan 02 13:39:38 bryan-System-Product-Name kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000001>
lines 1-23...skipping...
-- Logs begin at Wed 2020-12-16 01:50:13 IST, end at Sat 2021-01-02 14:00:33 IST. --
Jan 02 13:39:38 bryan-System-Product-Name kernel: Linux version 5.4.0-58-generic (buildd@lcy01-amd64-004) (gcc version 9.3.0 (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04)) #64-Ubuntu SMP Wed Dec 9 08:16:25 UTC 2020 (Ubuntu >
Jan 02 13:39:38 bryan-System-Product-Name kernel: Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-58-generic root=UUID=b24690f7-9b05-4faf-adf1-c10693c02c87 ro quiet splash atkbd.reset i8042.nomux vt.handoff=7
Jan 02 13:39:38 bryan-System-Product-Name kernel: KERNEL supported cpus:
Jan 02 13:39:38 bryan-System-Product-Name kernel:   Intel GenuineIntel
Jan 02 13:39:38 bryan-System-Product-Name kernel:   AMD AuthenticAMD
Jan 02 13:39:38 bryan-System-Product-Name kernel:   Hygon HygonGenuine
Jan 02 13:39:38 bryan-System-Product-Name kernel:   Centaur CentaurHauls
Jan 02 13:39:38 bryan-System-Product-Name kernel:   zhaoxin   Shanghai  
Jan 02 13:39:38 bryan-System-Product-Name kernel: x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x001: 'x87 floating point registers'
Jan 02 13:39:38 bryan-System-Product-Name kernel: x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x002: 'SSE registers'
Jan 02 13:39:38 bryan-System-Product-Name kernel: x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x004: 'AVX registers'
Jan 02 13:39:38 bryan-System-Product-Name kernel: x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x200: 'Protection Keys User registers'
Jan 02 13:39:38 bryan-System-Product-Name kernel: x86/fpu: xstate_offset[2]:  576, xstate_sizes[2]:  256
Jan 02 13:39:38 bryan-System-Product-Name kernel: x86/fpu: xstate_offset[9]:  832, xstate_sizes[9]:    8
Jan 02 13:39:38 bryan-System-Product-Name kernel: x86/fpu: Enabled xstate features 0x207, context size is 840 bytes, using 'compacted' format.
Jan 02 13:39:38 bryan-System-Product-Name kernel: BIOS-provided physical RAM map:
Jan 02 13:39:38 bryan-System-Product-Name kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000000000-0x0000000000000fff] reserved
Jan 02 13:39:38 bryan-System-Product-Name kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000001000-0x000000000008ffff] usable
Jan 02 13:39:38 bryan-System-Product-Name kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000090000-0x0000000000090fff] reserved
Jan 02 13:39:38 bryan-System-Product-Name kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000091000-0x000000000009ffff] usable
Jan 02 13:39:38 bryan-System-Product-Name kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000000a0000-0x00000000000fffff] reserved
Jan 02 13:39:38 bryan-System-Product-Name kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000100000-0x0000000009dfefff] usable
Jan 02 13:39:38 bryan-System-Product-Name kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000009dff000-0x0000000009ffffff] reserved
Jan 02 13:39:38 bryan-System-Product-Name kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000000a000000-0x000000000a1fffff] usable
Jan 02 13:39:38 bryan-System-Product-Name kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000000a200000-0x000000000a20dfff] ACPI NVS
Jan 02 13:39:38 bryan-System-Product-Name kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000000a20e000-0x000000000affffff] usable
Jan 02 13:39:38 bryan-System-Product-Name kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000000b000000-0x000000000b01ffff] reserved
Jan 02 13:39:38 bryan-System-Product-Name kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000000b020000-0x00000000ca684fff] usable
Jan 02 13:39:38 bryan-System-Product-Name kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000ca685000-0x00000000ca9b1fff] reserved
Jan 02 13:39:38 bryan-System-Product-Name kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000ca9b2000-0x00000000cab01fff] ACPI data
Jan 02 13:39:38 bryan-System-Product-Name kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000cab02000-0x00000000cadf6fff] ACPI NVS
Jan 02 13:39:38 bryan-System-Product-Name kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000cadf7000-0x00000000cbbfefff] reserved
Jan 02 13:39:38 bryan-System-Product-Name kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000cbbff000-0x00000000ccffffff] usable
Jan 02 13:39:38 bryan-System-Product-Name kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000cd000000-0x00000000cfffffff] reserved
Jan 02 13:39:38 bryan-System-Product-Name kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000f0000000-0x00000000f7ffffff] reserved
Jan 02 13:39:38 bryan-System-Product-Name kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fd200000-0x00000000fd2fffff] reserved
Jan 02 13:39:38 bryan-System-Product-Name kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fd600000-0x00000000fd7fffff] reserved
Jan 02 13:39:38 bryan-System-Product-Name kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fea00000-0x00000000fea0ffff] reserved
Jan 02 13:39:38 bryan-System-Product-Name kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000feb80000-0x00000000fec01fff] reserved
Jan 02 13:39:38 bryan-System-Product-Name kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fec10000-0x00000000fec10fff] reserved
Jan 02 13:39:38 bryan-System-Product-Name kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fec30000-0x00000000fec30fff] reserved
Jan 02 13:39:38 bryan-System-Product-Name kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fed00000-0x00000000fed00fff] reserved
Jan 02 13:39:38 bryan-System-Product-Name kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fed40000-0x00000000fed44fff] reserved
Jan 02 13:39:38 bryan-System-Product-Name kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fed80000-0x00000000fed8ffff] reserved
Jan 02 13:39:38 bryan-System-Product-Name kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fedc2000-0x00000000fedcffff] reserved
Jan 02 13:39:38 bryan-System-Product-Name kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fedd4000-0x00000000fedd5fff] reserved
Jan 02 13:39:38 bryan-System-Product-Name kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000ff000000-0x00000000ffffffff] reserved
Jan 02 13:39:38 bryan-System-Product-Name kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000100000000-0x000000042f37ffff] usable
Jan 02 13:39:38 bryan-System-Product-Name kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000042f380000-0x000000042fffffff] reserved
Jan 02 13:39:38 bryan-System-Product-Name kernel: NX (Execute Disable) protection: active
Jan 02 13:39:38 bryan-System-Product-Name kernel: e820: update [mem 0x90553018-0x90560867] usable ==> usable
Jan 02 13:39:38 bryan-System-Product-Name kernel: e820: update [mem 0x90553018-0x90560867] usable ==> usable
Jan 02 13:39:38 bryan-System-Product-Name kernel: e820: update [mem 0x90533018-0x90552857] usable ==> usable
Jan 02 13:39:38 bryan-System-Product-Name kernel: e820: update [mem 0x90533018-0x90552857] usable ==> usable
Jan 02 13:39:38 bryan-System-Product-Name kernel: extended physical RAM map:
Jan 02 13:39:38 bryan-System-Product-Name kernel: reserve setup_data: [mem 0x0000000000000000-0x0000000000000fff] reserved
lines 1-57























































-- Logs begin at Wed 2020-12-16 01:50:13 IST, end at Sat 2021-01-02 14:00:33 IST. --
Jan 02 13:39:38 bryan-System-Product-Name kernel: Linux version 5.4.0-58-generic (buildd@lcy01-amd64-004) (gcc version 9.3.0 (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04)) #64-Ubuntu SMP Wed Dec 9 08:16:25 UTC 2020 (U>
Jan 02 13:39:38 bryan-System-Product-Name kernel: Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-58-generic root=UUID=b24690f7-9b05-4faf-adf1-c10693c02c87 ro quiet splash atkbd.reset i8042.nomux vt.handof>
Jan 02 13:39:38 bryan-System-Product-Name kernel: KERNEL supported cpus:
Jan 02 13:39:38 bryan-System-Product-Name kernel:   Intel GenuineIntel
Jan 02 13:39:38 bryan-System-Product-Name kernel:   AMD AuthenticAMD
Jan 02 13:39:38 bryan-System-Product-Name kernel:   Hygon HygonGenuine
Jan 02 13:39:38 bryan-System-Product-Name kernel:   Centaur CentaurHauls
Jan 02 13:39:38 bryan-System-Product-Name kernel:   zhaoxin   Shanghai  
Jan 02 13:39:38 bryan-System-Product-Name kernel: x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x001: 'x87 floating point registers'
Jan 02 13:39:38 bryan-System-Product-Name kernel: x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x002: 'SSE registers'
Jan 02 13:39:38 bryan-System-Product-Name kernel: x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x004: 'AVX registers'
Jan 02 13:39:38 bryan-System-Product-Name kernel: x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x200: 'Protection Keys User registers'
Jan 02 13:39:38 bryan-System-Product-Name kernel: x86/fpu: xstate_offset[2]:  576, xstate_sizes[2]:  256
Jan 02 13:39:38 bryan-System-Product-Name kernel: x86/fpu: xstate_offset[9]:  832, xstate_sizes[9]:    8
Jan 02 13:39:38 bryan-System-Product-Name kernel: x86/fpu: Enabled xstate features 0x207, context size is 840 bytes, using 'compacted' format.
Jan 02 13:39:38 bryan-System-Product-Name kernel: BIOS-provided physical RAM map:
Jan 02 13:39:38 bryan-System-Product-Name kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000000000-0x0000000000000fff] reserved
Jan 02 13:39:38 bryan-System-Product-Name kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000001000-0x000000000008ffff] usable
Jan 02 13:39:38 bryan-System-Product-Name kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000090000-0x0000000000090fff] reserved
Jan 02 13:39:38 bryan-System-Product-Name kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000091000-0x000000000009ffff] usable
Jan 02 13:39:38 bryan-System-Product-Name kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000000a0000-0x00000000000fffff] reserved
Jan 02 13:39:38 bryan-System-Product-Name kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000100000-0x0000000009dfefff] usable
Jan 02 13:39:38 bryan-System-Product-Name kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000009dff000-0x0000000009ffffff] reserved
Jan 02 13:39:38 bryan-System-Product-Name kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000000a000000-0x000000000a1fffff] usable
Jan 02 13:39:38 bryan-System-Product-Name kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000000a200000-0x000000000a20dfff] ACPI NVS
Jan 02 13:39:38 bryan-System-Product-Name kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000000a20e000-0x000000000affffff] usable
Jan 02 13:39:38 bryan-System-Product-Name kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000000b000000-0x000000000b01ffff] reserved
Jan 02 13:39:38 bryan-System-Product-Name kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000000b020000-0x00000000ca684fff] usable
Jan 02 13:39:38 bryan-System-Product-Name kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000ca685000-0x00000000ca9b1fff] reserved
Jan 02 13:39:38 bryan-System-Product-Name kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000ca9b2000-0x00000000cab01fff] ACPI data
Jan 02 13:39:38 bryan-System-Product-Name kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000cab02000-0x00000000cadf6fff] ACPI NVS
Jan 02 13:39:38 bryan-System-Product-Name kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000cadf7000-0x00000000cbbfefff] reserved
Jan 02 13:39:38 bryan-System-Product-Name kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000cbbff000-0x00000000ccffffff] usable
Jan 02 13:39:38 bryan-System-Product-Name kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000cd000000-0x00000000cfffffff] reserved
Jan 02 13:39:38 bryan-System-Product-Name kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000f0000000-0x00000000f7ffffff] reserved
Jan 02 13:39:38 bryan-System-Product-Name kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fd200000-0x00000000fd2fffff] reserved
Jan 02 13:39:38 bryan-System-Product-Name kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fd600000-0x00000000fd7fffff] reserved
Jan 02 13:39:38 bryan-System-Product-Name kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fea00000-0x00000000fea0ffff] reserved
Jan 02 13:39:38 bryan-System-Product-Name kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000feb80000-0x00000000fec01fff] reserved
Jan 02 13:39:38 bryan-System-Product-Name kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fec10000-0x00000000fec10fff] reserved
Jan 02 13:39:38 bryan-System-Product-Name kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fec30000-0x00000000fec30fff] reserved
Jan 02 13:39:38 bryan-System-Product-Name kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fed00000-0x00000000fed00fff] reserved
Jan 02 13:39:38 bryan-System-Product-Name kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fed40000-0x00000000fed44fff] reserved
Jan 02 13:39:38 bryan-System-Product-Name kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fed80000-0x00000000fed8ffff] reserved
Jan 02 13:39:38 bryan-System-Product-Name kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fedc2000-0x00000000fedcffff] reserved
Jan 02 13:39:38 bryan-System-Product-Name kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fedd4000-0x00000000fedd5fff] reserved
Jan 02 13:39:38 bryan-System-Product-Name kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000ff000000-0x00000000ffffffff] reserved
Jan 02 13:39:38 bryan-System-Product-Name kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000100000000-0x000000042f37ffff] usable
Jan 02 13:39:38 bryan-System-Product-Name kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000042f380000-0x000000042fffffff] reserved
Jan 02 13:39:38 bryan-System-Product-Name kernel: NX (Execute Disable) protection: active
Jan 02 13:39:38 bryan-System-Product-Name kernel: e820: update [mem 0x90553018-0x90560867] usable ==> usable
Jan 02 13:39:38 bryan-System-Product-Name kernel: e820: update [mem 0x90553018-0x90560867] usable ==> usable
Jan 02 13:39:38 bryan-System-Product-Name kernel: e820: update [mem 0x90533018-0x90552857] usable ==> usable
```

Comment: Please run the `journalctl -b` command in a terminal and add a pastbin of the output to your question.

Comment: I added the command you suggested. Thx

Comment: Sorry @user2904033, I wasn't precise enough: please do the following for the entire kernel log: `journalctl -b | cat` and then paste the output to a *pastebin* like [link](https://pastebin.com/). Then you can post the Link of the generated pastebin in your question. This way you can avoid your log being viewed as spam or inflating your question.